# How to make linear regression with two dependent variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, feature-selection

I have a dataset with 90 independent variables (features) and two dependent variables (two classes or two column classes). Is there any way to make linear regression with both two classes at the same time?
I can make linear regression first with one class, then with second class, but I do not know how to combine both regressions.

Comment: The equation of 2 classes linear regression is still `(X^T X)^(-1) X^T y`.